# as3 air Upload issue with Android Upload file more than 400 KB

Tags: android, actionscript-3, upload, air, ftp

i am trying to upload a zip file using FTP, on Android when the file size less than 400 KB it is uploaded correctly, when it is more than 400 KB only 414 KB got uploaded and the result file is corrupted.
I tried same code from Windows and it is working with all sizes.

here is my code:

```
public function uploadZipFile() {
                //Socket instance which will be used to connect to ftp server
                s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOERR);
                s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onReturnData);
                s.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnectHandler);
                s.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
                //
                //Socket instance which will be used to connect to receive data sent by ftp server

                r.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onServData);
                r.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onPasvConn);
                r.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOERR);

                dtimer = new Timer(10,1);
                dtimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,function(){checkForStream();});
                this.addEventListener('dataReceived',onDataReceived);
var file:File = new File("XXX.zip");
initUpload(file)
            }
private function onReturnData(evt:ProgressEvent)
            {
                var d = s.readUTFBytes(s.bytesAvailable);
                trace(d);
                //check here for complete list of return codes and their meaning
                //- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes

                // the return message will have a 3 digit return code followed by a space and related message
                // if the 3 digit return code is followed by "-" the it will be a multiline message
                //-wait until the line with 3 digit code followed by space is delivered
                if(d.indexOf("220 ")>-1){
                    //connected to ftp server send user name to server
                    s.writeUTFBytes("USER "+ftp_username+"\n");
                    s.flush()
                }
                if(d.indexOf("331 ")>-1){
                    //Username accepted now send password to server
                    s.writeUTFBytes("PASS "+ftp_password+"\n");
                    s.flush()
                }
                if (d.indexOf("230") > -1 && d.indexOf("OK.") > -1)
                {
                    //Password accepted - lets enter passive mode and retrieve a list of files from a directory
                    //first enter passive mode
                    trace("Log in successful!");
                    s.writeUTFBytes("PASV \n");
                    s.flush();
                }
                var a = d.indexOf('227');
                if (a > -1)
                {
                    //Entering passive mode message will be returned along with it details of ip and port address will be returned
                    //-we have to connect to that address to receive the data
                    //format of the message will be: 227 Entering Passive Mode (209,190,85,253,148,206)
                    //the data inside brackets is the ip and port address, first four numbers represent IP and last 2 PORT
                    //the port value have to be calculated by multiplying the 5th number with 256 and adding the 6th number to it
                    //here in this example IP is 209.190.85.253 , PORT is (148*256)+206 = 38094
                    var st = d.indexOf("(",a);
                    var en = d.indexOf(")",a);
                    var str;
                    str = d.substring(st + 1,en);
                    var a2 = str.split(",");
                    var p1 = a2.pop();
                    var p2 = a2.pop();
                    var ip:String = a2.join(".");
                    var port:int=(p2*256)+(p1*1);       
                    r.connect(ip, port);
                }
                if(d.indexOf("226 ")>-1){
                    //Data Transfer completely lets disconnect from server
                    if (process=='download')
                    {
                        trace("DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE");

                    }
                    if (process=='upload')
                    {
                        trace("UPLOAD_COMPLETE");
                        informServer();
                    }
                    dispatchEvent(new Event("dataReceived"))
                }
                if(d.indexOf("221 ")>-1){
                    //LOGGED OUT from server 
                }
                if (d.indexOf("150 ") > -1)
                {
                    if (process == 'upload')
                    {
                        //Once data connection is established we can start sending the data to the server
                        startSendingData();
                    }
                }

            }
            private function onConnectHandler(evt:Event)
            {
                trace("CONNECTED TO FTP SERVER");
                //Client has connected to ftp server
                //you can also send multiple commands at same time like below or send step by step based on return code
                //-!
                //s.writeUTFBytes("USER username\n");
                //s.writeUTFBytes("PASS password\n"); 
                //s.flush();
            }//
            private function onPasvConn(evt:Event):void
            {
                trace("CONNECTED TO DATA PORT");
                //Now send LIST command to retrieve directory listings
                if (process == 'getDirList')
                {
                    //To retrive directory listings send following command
                    s.writeUTFBytes("LIST "+remoteFolderStr+"\n");
                }
                else if (process=='download')
                {
                    //To Download a file send following command
                    //RETR is the command followed by a space and path to file in remote server
                    s.writeUTFBytes("RETR "+remoteFolderStr+"/"+remoteFile+"\n");
                }
                else if (process=='upload')
                {
                    //To Upload a file send following command
                    //STOR is the command followed by a space and path wher to store the file in remote server
                    //-with the name of the file to be saved as..you can provide any name with extension
                    s.writeUTFBytes("STOR /"+localFile.name+"\n");
                }
                s.flush();
            }

            private function onServData(evt:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                //DATA RECEIVED FROM SERVER THRO DATA PORT
                var d = r.readUTFBytes(r.bytesAvailable);
                if (process == 'getDirList')
                {
                    d = r.readUTFBytes(r.bytesAvailable);
                    trace(d);
                }
                else if (process=='download')
                {
                    //As the data connection is established start writing the data to the fileStream
                    fileData = new ByteArray();//temporary bytearray object to write the incoming data
                    r.readBytes(fileData, 0, r.bytesAvailable);//write data to the temp bytearray
                    fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.bytesAvailable);//now write the bytearray to file stream
                    //instead you can directly write the data to file stream drom socket
                }
            }
            private function onIOERR(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace(evt.errorID+":"+evt.text);
            }

            private function checkForStream():void
            {
                //this function is used to check if the incoming data is fully written to the filestream and then close the filestream
                //-even if the ftp server dispatches that the file has been transfered...you application cn be still writing them to the filestream
                if(!r.connected){       
                    fileStream.close()
                }else{
                    //if the file is still been writing restart the timer
                    dtimer.reset()
                    dtimer.start()
                }


            }
            //
            public function initUpload(fileToUpload:File):void
            {
                //called when upload event is triggered
                localFile = fileToUpload;
                if (localFile.exists)
                {
                    //              this.remoteFolderStr=remote_folder.text
                    startUploadProcess();
                }
            }
                private function startUploadProcess():void
            {
                //create and open a fileStream
                fileStream=new FileStream();
                fileStream.open(localFile, FileMode.READ);
                process = "upload";
                fileData = new ByteArray();
                //You need to pass this command 'TYPE I' to set data transfer mode as binary
                s.writeUTFBytes("TYPE I\n");
                s.writeUTFBytes("PASV \n");
                s.flush();
            }
            private function startDownloadProcess():void
            {
                localFile = localFolder.resolvePath(remoteFile);
                fileStream=new FileStream();
                fileStream.open(localFile, FileMode.WRITE);
                process = "download";
                fileData = new ByteArray();
                s.writeUTFBytes("TYPE I\n");
                s.writeUTFBytes("PASV \n");
                s.flush();
            }
            private function startSendingData():void
            {
                interval = setInterval(sendData,300);
            }
            private function sendData():void
            {
                //file to be uploaded is sent as binary data
                if (fileStream.bytesAvailable <= 0)
                {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    r.close();
                    return;
                }
                if (fileStream.bytesAvailable < bufferSize)
                {
                    bufferSize = fileStream.bytesAvailable;
                }
                var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                fileStream.readBytes(ba, 0, bufferSize);
                r.writeBytes(ba, 0, ba.bytesAvailable);
                r.flush();
            }
            private function onDataReceived(evt:Event):void
            {
                if(process=='download'){        
                    dtimer.start();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone have this issue, i solved it by using small `bufferSize`, i set it to `100KB`,
i found it is attempt to close the connection before all data is sent when the buffer is big.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event OutputProgressEvent.OUTPUT_PROGRESS to check the number of bytes that has been written in the dataChannelConnection.